# parsing XML from URL in java

Tags: java, xml

Hello i have a big problem . i have to parse XML file from URL/HTTP and work on it in java , but i get exception always when i do it . address is ok because it is www of a bank . please help me

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class MainClass {
public static void main(String [] args){
    String url = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/gbp/2015-01-01/2015-01-31";   
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println ("Root element: " + 
                    doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**error :**

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at pl.parser.nbp.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)

**and second case :**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String [] args){
    String url = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-01/2012-01-31/";   
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory f = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(url);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println ("Root element: " + 
                    doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**error :**

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-01/2012-01-31/;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at pl.parser.nbp.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the URL returns data in JSON format. You see an XML in the browser because the way the browser negotiates a return type (via Accept header).

You can either parse the data as JSON, or change the URL to `http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/gbp/2015-01-01/2015-01-31?format=xml`.

Notice `?format=xml` at the end.

See the [User manual](http://api.nbp.pl/en.html#info).

Comment: thank you very much you save my life !! you are great !!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that readind directly from the URL, the site will return the data in json format. You need to open the URL, requesting xml

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String url = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-01/2012-01-31/";
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    f.setNamespaceAware(false);
    f.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    Document doc = b.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println ("Root element: " +  doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
}
```

This will print

```
Root element: ExchangeRatesSeries
```

Comment: `f.setNamespaceAware(false);` and `f.setValidating(false);` can be omitted as their default values is `false`